# When i use Drag and Drop, Dragged Object is deployed inside img instead div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a game in javascript, the game consist in drag and drop some items along the board.

The problem is some `<div>` have items inside (one `<img>`) and when i drop another, the dropped item go inside `<img>` instead `<div>`.

This is what i have before drop:

```
<div class="casa" id="39" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, this)">
    <img class="esgoto" id="esgoto39" src="./assets/esgoto.png" width="49" height="49" z-index="-1">
</div>
```

This is what i got after drop:

```
<div class="casa" id="39" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, this)">
    <img class="esgoto" id="esgoto39" src="./assets/esgoto.png" width="49" height="49" z-index="-1">
        <img class="plr" id="drag8" src="./assets/8.png" width="35" height="35" z-index="10" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this)">
    </img>
</div>
```

This is my js code:

```
    function drop(ev, nariz) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        let x = document.getElementById(nariz.id).children[0];
        let sinal = x.id;

        //other thing inside, each img.class have a specific action

}
```

this is what i want:

```
<div class="casa" id="39" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, this)">
    <img class="esgoto" id="esgoto39" src="./assets/esgoto.png" width="49" height="49" z-index="-1">
    <img class="plr" id="drag8" src="./assets/8.png" width="35" height="35" z-index="10" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this)">
</div>
```

Someone know how to do this?
PS: im avoid all frameworks and libraries. If possible i want make this "vanilla".

Comment: What does `data` evaluate to?

Comment: Sorry but i don't have sure. I think "var data" on one way to get the information from DOM... (i try moddify the code but i got an error). I use the data received to read the item dropped and the div information. From there i make loops and other statements.
I got that code from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData
I only know that w3schools and MDN says about that.